# In Lancer, what are valid targets for weapons that do not require line of sight?

Tags: weapons, line-of-sight, lancer-rpg

Weapons with the **seeking** or **arcing** tags can target enemies to which you do not have line of sight. But if you don't have line of sight, how would you know where the enemy is? Obviously you can use the ATHENA NHP to scry anywhere you want in range 50, but there are no-LoS weapons available at LL0, whereas the ATHENA NHP requires all 3 SSC Swallowtail licenses.

Have I missed a rule somewhere that says you know the location of any enemy that any of your allies have line of sight to? Do you automatically know the location of non-**hidden** foes (either within sensor range or anywhere in the battle)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### You know where non-hidden enemies in Sensors range are.

The description of Sensors in the Core Book states (p. 34; emphasis mine):

> SENSORS: Your mech’s SENSORS is the maximum distance (in spaces) over which a mech can detect enemies, use tech systems, and make tech attacks. **If a character is within your SENSORS and isn’t hiding, you know they’re there – even if you can’t directly see them.**

As such, you know the location of any enemy within your mech's Sensors value if it's not hidden.

Comment: That's why I didn't see it, it was squirreled away in the initial summary of mechs, and I kept looking in the Compendium section. Thanks!